# SQL query to find the cancellation rate of requests made between two dates using WITH

Tags: mysql, sql

**I'm trying to understand the right way to divide the count sums from two queries.**

I'm teaching myself sql and practising it on line.
Question:

Write a SQL query to find the cancellation rate of requests made between 2017-08-01 and 2017-08-03. The cancellation rate is given by dividing the number of cancelled requests by the total number of rides each day. The result table should have 2 Columns, namely Day that shows each day and Cancellation Rate that provides the cancellation rate of that day.
Table is:
[image]
What I tried was:

1. count cancelled ride rates per date
2. count all ride requests per date
3. divide both the counts per date

```
     with  
    cancelled_rides as 
    (select count(*) cancel_count, status, Request_id 
    from TRIPS 
    where status = 'cncld_driver' 
    group by state, Request_id)
     
    all_rides as ( 
    select count(*) day_count, status, Request_id 
    from TRIPS 
    group by state, Request_id) ,
     
    select cancelled_rides.Request_id as DAY, 
    (cancelled_rides.cancel_count/all_rides.day_count) as 'Cancellation Rate' 
    FROM cancelled_rides, all_rides;
```

Does this look right?  Note I purposefully ignored including date ranges as the table has only limited entries.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that a CTE helps at all for this query.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.Request_id as day, count(*) as total,
       sum( status = 'cncld_driver' ) as num_cancelled, 
       avg( status = 'cncld_driver' ) as cancellation_rate
from trips t
where request_id >= '2017-08-01' and 
      request_id < '2017-08-04'
group by request_id;
```

Calling a date "request_id" is rather confusing.  You should have a request id that is unique for each row and a separate column with the date/time.